# Alternative printer driver for Fuji Xerox DocuPrint P205b?

Tags: printing

Is there a driver for a similar printer that also happens to work for the Fuji Xerox P205 b?

I have tried the generic PCL 5 driver and the generic PostScript driver but they do not work.  Any other suggestions?  I'm on 10.10 (Maverick).

**Update** The Fuji Xerox website has a Linux driver download as an .iso image.  When you open the image you will see 3 drivers.  One for HP UX for the PA-RISC and another for Solaris SPARC and one for RedHat x86, x86-64, etc.  I picked the RedHat for my computer.  It invokes RPM so install that first.  The installation script crashes.

Comment: The Red Hat driver will not work for Ubuntu most likely because it is an RPM package; Ubuntu is based on Debian and so uses .deb packages instead. The two systems of package management are not compatible, just so you know why the Red Hat driver didn't work for you.

Comment: Use Computer Janitor and the RPM will get cleaned out.

Comment: The only thing [I can see on their website for Linux](http://www.fujixeroxprinters.com.au/en/support/Downloads.aspx?product=9933&category=5726&os=32768) is a firmware update, not a driver. That's not going to help. If you're able to see something else, please link to it.

Comment: Try installing the Mac driver (on a Mac), then copy the PPD file from the Mac to your linux machine.

Comment: @Oli, I can't find the *nix drivers anymore. I think it was on one of the FujiXerox eastern hemisphere websites such as perhaps Australia, NZ, or Japan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

foo2hbpl contains driver of p105b/p205b .

The website is http://foo2hbpl.rkkda.com/

I tested it in archlinux.

Works very smoothly with cups.

Enjoy it.

Comment: Well, with Ubuntu 12.04, it provides a driver for my DocuPrint cp105 b, but alas, they are not friends - I only get blank pages and flashing exclamation marks on my printer ):

Comment: Tested with Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Tested with Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Broiyan.

Dang! I feared that was the only way to get this printer going.  I have sent an e-mail to Xerox Support.  I'm hoping they can give some guidance on how to get it working.   I'll post again once I have an answer from them.

Thanks again,
KN

OK, here is the response I got from Xerox.  It's not very helpful :(

---

Hello,

This is a GDI printer and is not compatible with Linux and UNIT operating systems.

Regards,
Hamed Hala
Customer Support

Fuji Xerox Printers
Beacon Business Park, Fuji Xerox House
14A Rodborough Road, FRENCHS FOREST NSW 2086 AUSTRALIA

T: 1800 811 177 F: +61 2 9452 7031
Email : Hamed.Hala@aus.fujixerox.com
Web :  www.fujixerox.com.au

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please refrain from posting answers which don't present a solution to the problem. I have flagged this post for deletion; please see the [faq] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

install the package alien from your repository, it will allow you to convert the rpm package to a .deb file.

instead of installing the newly created deb package, extract the files.
with dpkg -x nameOfConvertedPackage.deb hopefully it contains the stuff you need when selecting printer driver from the intall wizzard.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an alternate driver to get the Fuji Xerox DocuPrint P205b working on Ubuntu 12.04.

1. Install VirtualBox.
2. Install VirtualBox Oracle Extensions.
3. Attach the USB cable to the printer and power up the printer.
4. Run VirtualBox and go to Machine/Settings/USB.
5. Select checkbox "USB 2.0 EHCI Controller".  If it is greyed out and disabled, experiment to get it enabled.
6. Add a USB Filter by selecting the FX DocuPrint P205b.
7. In VirtualBox Devices/USB select the FX DocuPrint P205b.  This allows the guest operating system to see the device.
8. Install Windows 7 as a guest operating system in VirtualBox and boot it.
9. In the Devices dialog use "Add Printer" and use a Local Port and select the "USB Virtual Printer Port".
10. Install the driver by either selecting from the updated/downloaded list or use "Have Disk".  As of 2012 September 7, the very extensive downloaded list does not have listed the FX DocuPrint P205b.
11. The test print job will probably go to the bit bucket.  Reboot the guest operating system and do a test print.
12. In VirtualBox, the Devices menu has "Install Guest Additions".  Use it.
13. In Machine/Settings/Shared Folders, add a shared folder to the directory above everything you would ever want to print, such as `/home/MyName`.  In Windows 7 that folder will be assigned a drive letter.

Comment: rather a heavy answer, isn't it?